# OpenSSH client on Windows 10 connection error

Tags: windows, ssh

On Windows 10 Enterprise, I can't connect via ssh to a linux machine. `192.168.0.3` is a valid local IP, i can connect to it with `putty`.

```
PS C:\Users\elsneste> ssh 192.168.0.3
CreateProcessW failed error:193
ssh_askpass: posix_spawnp: Unknown error
Host key verification failed.

PS C:\Users\elsneste> ssh -V
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
```

This is a quite fresh Windows 10 installation. I copied the `.ssh` folder from the previous machine, but that was maybe a bad idea.

I then renamed the `.ssh` folder to `._ssh` to inactivate it, with no effect.

Windows Openssh-feature has been reinstalled. again, no effect.

Git for windows is also installed. Same error in *git cmd*, no error in *git bash*

Comment: OpenSSH 8.1 is quite old, with it looking like 8.x is now on 8.9, and 9.x has been out for a while, so perhaps 8.1 is trying to use methods that are no longer supported or have been removed through one of the vulnerability discoveries that have come up over the last few years? Perhaps try updating to a more recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
delete the environment variable
`DISPLAY=UNDEFINED` (or similar)
from the windows environment variables.